# Rails: How to run parent object validation when child object is saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models , Post and User . code is as shown below

```
class User
 has_one :post
 validates_associated :post
 validates_presence_of :name
end

class Post
 belongs_to :user
 validates_presence_of :description
 #validates_associated :user
end

user = User.new
user.build_post # creating post without description
user.save 
user.valid? => false  #This is working as expected

post = Post.new
post.build_user
post.save
post.valid? => true
```

I was expecting post.valid? to return false because i have provided empty '`name'` . It looks like validation defined on user model is not running when i am saving post object.  i can't use `validates_associated :user` in post model because it will give 'circular dependency' error .  my question is if `validates_associated :user` cannot be used in post model then what is the alternative?

Comment: What rails version

Answer (score 0):

As per https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated:

> validates_associated doesn’t work with has_one associations

The recommandation is to use `validates` on the `has_one` association as such:

```
class User
 has_one :post, validates: true
end
```

Note that I haven't tested this and am just basing my recommandation on that source.